# Simple Eclipse plugin open new document

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

How to make an eclipse plugin open a new-generated document in the main view (something like a hello.txt file) when the user switches to its perspective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would be typical code for this task:

```
String fileContents = ...;
IFile file = ...;
file.create(new ByteArrayInputStream(fileContents.getBytes()), true, null);
FileEditorInput input = new FileEditorInput(file);
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().
    getActivePage().openEditor(input, THE_EDITOR_ID);
```